# Excel - Custom Ribbon Buttons Not Working After File Rename & Relocation

Tags: excel, vba, ribbon

I have written some macros in VBA and created a custom Ribbon tab with said buttons placed on it.

[image]

I have since renamed my file and relocated it elsewhere; the VBA has copied across just fine (i.e. it has remained within the project as expected) and the code runs perfectly when run from the VBA editor (I access this using Alt + F11).  However, the buttons (see image) no longer work, instead referring to the previous version of the file.

Is there a simple way to get the buttons to update/"refresh" without having to manually create the Ribbon tab once again and adding all of the buttons accordingly?

I have imported a previous version of the Ribbon (that I had initially exported for backup purposes) but the buttons still seem to refer to the previous version of the document.

Any ideas and suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How did you create the ribbon buttons? If you did it through the Excel UI (i.e. the Customize the Ribbon option) then they point at a specific file path, that doesn't change. You really need to edit the CustomUI (or CustomUI14) part of the workbook: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win001.htm

Comment: The buttons were created through the Excel UI as you describe.  I am unable to install the CustomUI software due to restrictions on the machine that I use to work on this project.  Can you suggest another way to somehow "transfer" the buttons or even update the file reference?

Comment: You may be able to edit the paths in the Excel.officeUI file - usually in C:\users\user_name\appdata\local\microsoft\office

Comment: You should probably seek approval to install the CustomUI editor. You need it to do your job. Otherwise, if you have an install of VSTO you can use that to access the CustomUI xml.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's and old question but maybe my answer can help others. I had the same problem and had to change the registry entry. Go to start menu-> run -> regedit.exe -> HKEY_CURRENT_USER -> Software -> Microsoft -> Office -> 12.0 (if office 2007) -> Excel -> then look for the entry with the old add-in file path and update the value to the new location (should be item "OPENX"). That did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I got an easy solution for anyone having the same issue.

I've encountered the same problem when migrating between computers (as well as a different version of Windows, and office). Upon noticing the problem, I first started to re-customize the ribbon. It worked, but of course that was cumbersome and inefficient. I figured there may be a way to edit the exported customization file ("Excel Customizations.exportedUI"), and had a hunch it was an XML file. Indeed!

**The solution, therefore, is straightforward:**

1. Rename "Excel Customizations.exportedUI" to "Excel Customizations.exportedUI.xml" (i.e. add a .xml suffix)
2. Using any XML or text editor, replace the locations of macros to your new location.

Note that there are at least two global Find & Replace operations you'd want to do:

There are occurrences with backslashes (e.g.
D:\AdaLovelace\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART\PERSONAL.XLSB!)

...and then there are occurrences where underscores replace backslashes, e.g.
D:_AdaLovelace_AppData_Roaming_Microsoft_Excel_XLSTART_PERSONAL.XLSB_

Of course, you'd want to keep things the way they are, so do one replace where you have underscores, and one with backslashes.

3. Save the file and close it. Rename it again to take out the ".xml" suffix.
4. Go back to Excel on the new machine, right-click the ribbon ->customize the ribbon ->import the modified file

When prompted whether you want to replace all the customization, say yes.

Voila! Victory!

*[I imported Ribbon + Quick Access Toolbar customizations from Office 10/Win7 to Office 2019/Win 10].*